# Accused in Spain, but no police interview

Tags: spain, legal

I have been accused (I believe), by a security guard of assaulting him.  I did not do this, and was no where near him at the time of the alleged offense.  However he has made a false denuncia, and has accessed his companies data base to get my details.  The Guardia has not 'interviewed' me, only telling me that this man made a denuncia against me.  I have not heard back from the Guardia in over two weeks now.  What annoys me is that there is a denuncia with my name on it, and no one seems to be dealing with it.  I cannot afford a lawyer to act on my behalf.  Does anyone have any suggestions and advice?

Comment: Does this have anything to do with being an expat? Sound off topic to me.

Comment: Yes, I am British Citizen, and the accuser has in the past told my husband that no one would believe anything he said as he is a foreigner. (Sorry maybe I should have added that to the initial question.)

Comment: While there may be bias, there is not much advice we can give here unless a lawyer happens to surf by and see your post. Contact the embassy for a list of lawyers who will work pro-bono.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To find out the status you can go to the court's *decanato* and say that you want details of a *denuncia* which you believe has been made against you.

Note that the Spanish justice system is very slow but expects everyone else to be very fast. It's quite possible that nothing will happen for three months and then you'll get a notification of a trial date in a week's time. Only when they give that notification do they give you a copy of the *denuncia*.

If it's for anything more serious than a *delito leve* then you can must have a lawyer, and the court will provide one. I don't know exactly how that works out in terms of proving inability to pay. If it's a *delito leve* then they will tell you that you have the choice of coming with a lawyer or not but that the court won't provide one, and will possibly even tell you that you don't need to have one, it's no big deal. That's a lie: only your lawyer can cross-examine the other party and their witnesses.